# Getting Equation From a Table

Tags: functions

I have a simple problem that i am struggling with. In short i am given a number of volts a battery is putting out and from this i need to figure out how full it is. I have a table of 100 values, one corresponding to each percentage and i need to create and equation that if i plug in an amount of volts will give me a percentage value from it. I tried creating a trend line using excel, but it was hundreds off. Any advice on how to do this and or what software could do this would be appreciated. I've included one of the tables below.

1470,   100%

1440,   99%

1409,   98%

1386,   97%

1365,   96%

1348,   95%

1332,   94%

1317,   93%

1305,   92%

1295,   91%

1284,   90%

1275,   89%

1266,   88%

1258,   87%

1252,   86%

1245,   85%

1239,   84%

1234,   83%

1227,   82%

1225,   81%

1217,   80%

1213,   79%

1208,   78%

1202,   77%

1197,   76%

1193,   75%

1187,   74%

1184,   73%

1178,   72%

1176,   71%

1170,   70%

1167,   69%

1161,   68%

1158,   67%

1154,   66%

1149,   65%

1146,   64%

1142,   63%

1138,   62%

1136,   61%

1132,   60%

1128,   59%

1125,   58%

1122,   57%

1118,   56%

1117,   55%

1112,   54%

1109,   53%

1107,   52%

1104,   51%

1099,   50%

1096,   49%

1093,   48%

1090,   47%

1088,   46%

1085,   45%

1081,   44%

1080,   43%

1076,   42%

1073,   41%

1069,   40%

1066,   39%

1062,   38%

1058,   37%

1056,   36%

1052,   35%

1049,   34%

1044,   33%

1041,   32%

1038,   31%

1034,   30%

1030,   29%

1026,   28%

1021,   27%

1019,   26%

1013,   25%

1010,   24%

1004,   23%

1000,   22%

995,    21%

989,    20%

984,    19%

980,    18%

973,    17%

969,    16%

962,    15%

956,    14%

950,    13%

943,    12%

935,    11%

929,    10%

920,    9%

913,    8%

904,    7%

895,    6%

883,    5%

871,    4%

858,    3%

842,    2%

823,    1%

806,    0%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that it's easier to get to a fit of the output in millivolts as a function of the battery capacity percentage. A plot of the capacity as a function of the percentage shows the problem:

[image: capacity as a function of voltage]

This looks like an S-curve, but we have a nonzero slope at the end, which is not going to yield a good fit. Also an S-curve fit requires using non-linear fit methods, which can be awkward to implement correctly. If we interchange the two variables then the graph of percentage as a function of the millivolts looks like this:

[image: reversed]

This looks superficially like a 3rd degree curve with a clear point of inflexion in the middle. So, we can try to make a 3rd degree fit using straightforward linear fit methods. What you then find is that the fit is not so good at the edges. Such problems are then easy to remedy by adding exponential functions that are small everywhere except at the edges. I've obtained a good fit using a trial function of the form:

$$f(x) = a + b x + c x^2 +d x^3 + u \exp\left[\left(\frac{25-x}{5}\right)\right] +  v \exp\left[\left(\frac{x-75}{5}\right)\right]$$

This yields the fit values $a = 872.36$, $b = 7.42058$, $c = -0.0862508$, $d = 0.000583907$, $u = -0.452178$, $v = 0.897504$. The graph with the fit function looks like this:

[image: fit]

Using nonlinear fitting methods we can try to fit the original data of the battery power as a function of the voltage, it turns out that it's quite difficult to get a good fit. Using Mathematica, the built in function "NonlinearModelFit" does not work well, it fails to converge for my choice of fit function. So, I had to use this to get to a reasonable fit with an inferior fit function and then try a linear combination of the output and another function using the linear fit method. I found the following result:

$$
\begin{split}
f(x) =& \frac{100.044 \left[\exp\left(0.0119075x\right)-12035\right]}{\exp\left(0.0119075 x\right)+468872} +\\
& 0.00023108 x \exp\left(\frac{x-1420}{40}\right)
\end{split}
$$

The graph with this function looks like:

[image: new]

Comment: Do you have any reference on (straightforward) linear fit methods ? (That is where "magic happens" for me in your answer.)

Comment: @Mirko I'll add a ref, but it's just least squares fit methods where you find the coefficients that minimize the sum of the squared differences. What then matters is that the fit function is linear in the coefficients, so you can have $y = a f_1(x) + b f_2(x) + c f_3(x)$ and the $f_i(x)$ can be extremely complicated functions but the fact that you're fitting with a linear combination of these functions here makes it a linear algebra problem to find the coefficients also standard software can be used.

Comment: I agree with you that is much easier to find the value as a 3rd degree curve. The issue i'm having is that in the end i need to plug in a value from approximately 800 to 1500 and get an output between 0 and 100 that approximates the table.

Comment: @Falderol I've added the results of a fit the other way around obtained using nonlinear fit methods.